# How to use ESM tests with jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, node-modules

**My setup**

- Node v14.16.0
- I have one test file that contains a simple test written with ESM modules (`import`).
- In `package.json` I have a script (following [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) adapted to Windows): `"test": "set \"NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules\" && npx jest"`
- My tests are run w/ `npm run test` (the script above)

**My goal:** Run the ESM tests using jest.

**My attempts:**

### (1) CommonJS App w/ .js test

- `package.json` contains `"type": "commonjs"`
- Test file named `test.js`
- Error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` (This is expected because the test is being run as a commonjs file.)

### (2) CommonJS App w/ .mjs test

- `package.json` contains `"type": "commonjs"`
- Test file named `test.mjs`
- Error: `No tests found` (Jest isn't finding the file?)

### (3) ESM App w/ .js or .mjs

- `package.json` now has `"type": "module"`
- Test file named `test.mjs` or `test.js`
- Error: `ReferenceError: module is not defined at ...jest.config.js:6:1`

### (4) CommonJS App and CommonJS test

- `package.json` contains `"type": "commonjs"`
- Test file named `test.js` but using the commonjs `require` syntax (and without the ESM modules I'd like to include); Note that **this is not what I want**, but included just to show there's nothing wrong with the test itself.
- Test runs fine and passes

Comment: You mentioned your test file is an ES module, but what about your tested file? Also, why do you mention you used a test file as Common JS module (in #4) if what you seem to actually need is an ES module test?

Comment: Did you try to use `cross-env` with any of your attempts? Note the comment from the second step on the Jest documentation about using ESM that you linked to: "On Windows, you can use cross-env to be able to set environment variables."

Comment: @OfirD -- My tests are super simple placeholders, not even hooked up to test files yet, and none of the errors point to that sort of thing being an issue. For #4 I explain that it's included just to show that the test files are not problematic.

Comment: @Morgan -- I didn't try `cross-env` because all the developers for this project are on windows machines, and I'd prefer one less dependency. `set` works for Windows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1)

Comment: @Luke I hear you about one less dependency. I only brought it up because the answer I provided did not use `NODE_OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 48):

Here are the steps I took to run Jest with a test using ESM. The source files under test were also written using ESM.

1. Set my node version to 14.16.0
2. Install Jest:

   ```
   npm i jest -D
   ```
3. Add `"type": "module"` to `package.json`
4. Update `test` script in `package.json`:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules ./node_modules/.bin/jest"
   }
   ```
5. Create a `jest.config.js` file with the following content:

   ```
   export default { transform: {} }
   ```
6. Have at least one test that could be found using the default [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) (mine was inside `__tests__` dir)
7. Run tests:

   ```
   npm test
   ```

There is a more complete example in the [magic-comments-loader](https://github.com/morganney/magic-comments-loader) repository on GitHub.

Comment: This seems to be the same as my attempt #3, but for some reason this now worked for me. I'm not sure that your step 5 is required with default configuration. I also switched to `.mjs` for test files, so added to my `jest.config.mjs` file: `"mjs"` to `moduleFileExtensions`, and `"**/?(*.)+(spec|test).(m)js?(x)"` to `testMatch`.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. I added and use step 5 because it comes straight from the [jest documentation on using esm](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) (bullet item #1). Note that the default [`transform`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object) uses `babel-jest`.

Comment: Jest 27.1.1 includes support for mocking ESM imports: https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases/tag/v27.1.1

Comment: @Luke Did you figure this out? It seems you can't have `"type": "commonjs"` and write tests as `.mjs`.

Comment: Thank you so much, step 5) was exactly what I was missing! You fixed my day! :)

Comment: I'm getting this error after add the test flag 
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')") any thouths?

Comment: @KleberGermano and anyone else who comes across this, I was getting the same `basedir=$(dirname` error on my machine. After some googling, seems it's a Windows issue, likely due to the fact there is also a .cmd file with the same name in that directory, so Windows file resolution picks that file instead of the one with no extension. Workaround is to point to the file in the actual module dir: `./node_modules/jest/bin/jest`

Comment: I fixed it changing the test property to: "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js" from the documentation
https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/docs/ecmascript-modules

Comment: As of 2022/08: Step 3 is not needed. Step 4 nees the command `node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest`. Step 5 i snot needed.

Answer (score 9):

After a lot of fiddling, this is my successful setup (the parts that matter):

- `package.json` has

```json
  "type": "commonjs",
  "script": {
    "test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"
  }
```

- `jest.config.mjs` (yes, esModule)

```
export default {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "mjs",
    // must include "js" to pass validation https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12116
    "js",
  ],
  testRegex: `test\.mjs$`,
};
```

That having to include `"js"` is a historic relic from the times modules where obviously .js files. Follow https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12116 for update.

Answer (score 8):

For me to work it was only necessary to set script "test" as follows:

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest"
```

and yeah, don't forget -> `npm i cross-env jest`

Comment: This one worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the minimum you need. Props to @Luke for the comment above with the testMatch answer I needed.

1. `package.json` -  Make sure `"type": "module"` is in there
2. `jest.config.js` - Add this glob to your `testMatch` array: `"**/?(*.)+(spec|test).(m)js"`
3. Make sure your test file(s) end in `.spec.mjs` or `.test.mjs` to match the glob
4. Set your `npm test` script to `node --experimental-vm-modules ./node_modules/.bin/jest`

That's it. You ***do not need*** the transform setting in the jest config as [the documentation suggests](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules).

Comment: I just tested this today and I did not need step 1.  Also for step 2, I just took the current default `testMatch` and changed it to have an optional `m` before the `[tj]` glob pattern. This was the best tip I found to set this up, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

in my case, leaving

- `"type": "module"` in package.json

and renaming

- `jest.config.js` to `jest.config.cjs`
- `babel.config.js` to `babel.config.cjs`

worked

Comment: This is the correct answer. This is similar to what you must do for other config files. For example, here are the eslint guidelines for ESM: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [@morganney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258174/morganney) answer but I was getting this error: `"basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")..."`. so to make it work I used the property
`"test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"` from the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/docs/ecmascript-modules).

Thus my package.json ended up configured like this:

```json
 {
      "type": "module", 
        "jest": {
          "transform": {}
        },
         "scripts": {
            "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
         }
       "dependencies": {
        "jsdom": "^17.0.0",
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing [`esm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) npm package

```
npm i --save-dev esm
```

did the trick for me without any additional jest configuration. Cause ESM package has a `require` function that is able to substitute for CJS require. So you'll be overriding the CJS require function with ESM one in every jest file that tests ESM.

So for instance to test `yourESModule.js` which is an ESM with jest, you would start your `yourESModule.test.js` with the following:

```
require = require('esm')(module)
const { yourFunction } = require('./yourESModule')
```

Btw, my jest version is `"jest": "^29.6.1"`

Then just run:

```
npx jest
```

Hope this helps!