# Jest not recognizing import statement in a Node.js and Lerna monorepo

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-modules, lerna

I'm working on a Lerna monorepo project which includes multiple Node.js packages. Each package uses ES6 syntax, notably the import statement for modules.

When I try to run Jest tests, I'm encountering the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

This error is triggered by any file using the import statement.

Here are some relevant details about my setup:

- Node version: v18.16.0 (set by .nvmrc and being recognized)
- Using Lerna for monorepo management
- Babel is configured and works correctly for the build process
- The jest.config.js and babel.config.js files are in the project's root directory
- Each package has "type": "module" in its package.json

Here are some files:

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
transform: {
  '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
},
};
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = { presets: [
['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
],
};
```

lerna.json:

```
{
 "$schema": "node_modules/lerna/schemas/lerna-schema.json",
 "useWorkspaces": true,
  "packages": ["services/*"],
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

Still, Jest doesn't seem to recognize the import statements in my files.
What could be the issue and how might I solve it?

Comment: Do you want to run jest in esm or cjs?

Comment: Otherwise try adding `modules: 'commonjs'` to preset-env.

Comment: I want to run jest in esm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956636/how-to-use-esm-tests-with-jest