# Next/jest setup "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export" with Swiper.js

Tags: jestjs, es6-modules, swiper.js

When I run tests on the project, I have the next problem on my project after intalling Swiper

```
 export { default as Swiper, default } from './core/core.js';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Does somebody know how to resolve it? On the project I'm using `pnpm`

I want to fix an error described above

Comment: This question comes up all the time. Not specific to swiper, but the fact that jest’s default module system is CJS unless you explicitly configure it to use ESM. Either find a version of your dependency published as CJS or run jest in ESM. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956636/how-to-use-esm-tests-with-jest/69059786#69059786. There is also options to transpile swiper in jest’s config. Read the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your example. But this won't work. You propose to crush the existing configuration that was in production. And completely rewrite all test structures. 

For future, I've found an unswer, https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/12984#issuecomment-1198204906

Forgot to mentioned that I'm using next/jest

Comment: Yeah, that was the part about "There is also options to transpile swiper in jest's config" that you clearly didn't parse correctly.

Comment: No prob. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Found an unswer that was helps me - https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/12984#issuecomment-1198204906