# NPM test script fails with "Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]"

Tags: npm, jestjs, es6-modules, commonjs

I'm trying to update dependencies for my React Node project, and any update to `package.json` at all, including deleting `yarn.lock` and installing the same dependencies fresh with `yarn`, causes `yarn test` (which is set to `cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest .` to fail with the following warning:

```js
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /PROJECT/node_modules/string-width/index.js from /PROJECT/node_modules/cliui/build/index.cjs not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /PROJECT/node_modules/cliui/build/index.cjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Running `npx jest` causes the same error, even though running just `jest` does not. My local environment works just fine, the same as before the updates, but running tests through the NPM scripts is broken. Since that's how our CI/CD runs tests, I can't just ignore this and run tests directly.

I have tried adding `"type": "module"` to `package.json`, but that breaks the local server because it's running on Express, and all those files use CommonJS.

Node version: 18.15.0

NPM version: 9.8.1

Jest version: 27.5.1 (same thing happens with versions 28.x and 29.x)

Comment: Some of your chosen deps are esm only. You need to load them with dynamic import, choose older versions that still use cjs, or run jest as esm.

Comment: @morganney How do I run jest as ESM? I've added `"type": "module"` to `package.json` and managed to fix all the new problems caused by that, but running jest through yarn is still causing the same error. I've also tried running jest with the `--experimental-vm-modules` flag according to Jest's EcmaScript Modules page, but no dice.

Comment: You write your tests in esm and then disable the default  jest `transform` mostly. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69059786/258174